# discord.js interval message with fetch

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently  trying to make bot that's sending message every hour the dogecoin price but for some reason its sending it every second
I am new to this stuff so sorry if I am asking stupid question

```
setInterval(async function() {
    fetch(`https://chain.so/api/v2/get_price/DOGE/USD`, { "method": "GET" })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json.data.prices[1])
        let doge1 = json.data.prices[1]
        let doge2 = json.data.prices[0]
        var seconds = `${doge1.time}`; // Some arbitrary value
        var date = new Date(seconds*1000); // multiply by 1000 because Date() requires miliseconds
        var timeStr = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
        var seconds1 = `${doge2.time}`; // Some arbitrary value
        var date1 = new Date(seconds *1000); // multiply by 1000 because Date() requires miliseconds
        var timeStr1 = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
        
        const doge = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#2ECC71')
          .setFooter('Success')
.setThumbnail('https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/8f8/e12/51b54d13d65d8ee3773ce32da03e1fa220-dogecoin.rsquare.w1200.jpg')
          .setTitle('DOGECOIN')
          .setDescription('The price of DOGE')
          .addFields(
              { name: 'Exchange', value: `${doge1.exchange}` , inline: true },
              { name: 'Price', value: `${doge1.price}`, inline: true },
              { name: 'Price base', value: `${doge1.price_base}` , inline: true },
              { name: 'Time', value: `${timeStr}`, inline: false },
              { name: 'Exchange', value: `${doge2.exchange}` , inline: true },
              { name: 'Price', value: `${doge2.price}`, inline: true },
              { name: 'Price bsae', value: `${doge2.price_base}` , inline: true },
              { name: 'Time', value: `${timeStr1}`, inline: true },
          )
         message.channel.send(doge)
        // message.channel.send('<@484786165715697664> <@794297709237764126> <@479021067856511008>')
    })
}, 1 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(fn, 1 * 1000)` means, run it every 1000ms (1sec). `1*1000` should be `1*60*60*1000`. That's 1 hour times 60 minutes times 60 seconds times 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `1000`ms to your `setInterval()` function. That is equal to 1s.

To run your code every hour, you need to convert an hour to milliseconds.

```
setInterval(async function () {
  // Your Code
}, 60 * 60 * 1000) // 60m x 60s x 1000ms = 1 hour
```